# How to insert update delete treeview Nodes that are populated from Database?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

in my project i have a treeview that is populated from database, i know how to insert update delete in a treeview when it's not populated from a database, and when i use that code it does'nt effect what's in the database obviously, so in my case i want to do that effecting database, my code does nothin, i want some help ! Thanks !

Here is the code that i've tried :

i'm Loading my treeview whith a procedure :

```
     class Methodes{
         public static SqlDataAdapter adap;
     }
     Methodes.adap = new SqlDataAdapter("CLAISSIFICATIONORDRE", con);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            Methodes.adap.Fill(ds);
```

insert :

```
    string Query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Classifications] ([Texte]) VALUES  ='" + this.AddTxtBx.Text + "' WHERE idParent ='"+treeView.SelectedNode.Text.Trim()+"'   ";

        TreeNode Node = new TreeNode(Query);

        treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(Node);

        treeView.Refresh();
```

Delete :

```
   string Query = "DELETE FROM Classifications WHERE id ='" + treeView.SelectedNode.Text.Trim() + "'";

        TreeNode Node = new TreeNode(Query);

        treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Remove(Node);


        treeView.Refresh();
```

Update :

```
 string Query = "UPDATE [dbo].[Classifications] SET [Texte] ='" + this.EditTxtBx.Text + "'";

        TreeNode Node = new TreeNode(Query);

        treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(Node);

        treeView.Refresh();
```

Comment: How are you loading the data from database in tree view?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i'm loding it with a sotred procedure

Comment: Insert, Update and Delete queries can not simply add/update/delete nodes in treeview. You need to execute those queries against database and rebind the treeview to load the fresh data from the database...